# MYSQL returning out of bounds date

Tags: mysql

I have a DB table with the following structure:

```
user_id (int) | status (int) | param1 (varchar) | param2 (varchar) | start (date) | external_id (int)
```

I am doing the following query:

The DB table has the following structure.

```
select
    * 
from
    `users_stuff` 
where
    (
        `status` >= '8' 
        and `start` between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-11' 
        and `outside_url` is not null 
        and (
            `param1` = '1' 
            and `param2` = 'A'
        ) 
        or (
            `param1` = '0' 
            and `param2` = 'B'
        ) 
        and `user_id` = '14' 
        and `external_id` is not null
    ) 
    and `deleted_at` is null
```

however when the results are returned to me I see items with the "start" set to the 12th of July. Why is that? What is wrong here that would cause that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the DB scheme and sample db records?

Comment: Do not tag with unrelated tags. I removed `php` and `laravel` tags. Feel free to get them back once it will be justified by your question content.

Comment: Sorry I only used the Laravel tag because I am using Laravel and this was generated by Eloquent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the placement of the OR condition is casuing this behaviour. I have updated the query as below:

```
select
    * 
from
    `users_stuff` 
where
    (
        `status` >= '8' 
        and `start` between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-11' 
        and `outside_url` is not null 
        and (
            `param1` = '1' 
            and `param2` = 'A'

        or 
            `param1` = '0' 
            and `param2` = 'B'
        ) 
        and `user_id` = '14' 
        and `external_id` is not null
    ) 
    and `deleted_at` is null
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is wrong here that would cause that?

Your query looks faulty at first glance and can lead to unexpected behavior, for example you do

```
`status` >= '8'
```

however `status` is `int`, not s `string` as you treat it. The same happens for all the other integers which for unknown reasons are quoted in your quest. So fix the syntax and remove all the quotes around integers, so i.e. said

```
`status` >= '8'
```

become

```
`status` >= 8
```

PS: As small "optimization", I'd move `and`deleted_at`is null` at the beginning of your `where` clause: `where`deleted_at`is null and ...` as there's no point evaluating remaining conditions if `deleted_at` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

Look to your OR stament after AND.
Enclose your OR statement between ().

For example  WHERE ( AND criterium OR criterium) AND criterium.